# Numeric Field Overflow when Subtracting from Numeric value in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Relatively new to Postgres, and been having trouble subtracting a value from a NUMERIC(4,2) value type in an update statement. The following code:

```
UPDATE  Tickets
SET     ticketPrice = ticketPrice-3
FROM    Showings
WHERE   Showings.priceCode = modTicket
```

Elicits the following error:

```
ERROR: numeric field overflow
  Detail: A field with precision 4, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^2.
```

`ticketPrice` has the value type of NUMERIC(4,2). How do I make this subtraction? There are no possible values that this subtraction would cause to extend past two decimal points, or in the negatives at all. The only values that this subtraction applies to are 5.00, 3.50, and 8.00.

Comment: Are you positive that those are the only three values?  The query `SELECT DISTINCT ticketPrice FROM Tickets JOIN Showings ON Showings.priceCode = modTicket` only returns those three values?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find out the error source like this:

```
do $$
    declare r record;
    foo numeric(4,2);
begin
    for r in (select t.* from Tickets as t, Showings as s where s.priceCode = t.modTicket) loop
        foo := r.ticketPrice - 3;
    end loop;
exception
    when others then raise notice '%', r;
    raise;
end $$;
```

Example:

```
do $$
    declare r record;
    foo numeric(1);
begin
    for r in (with t(x,y) as (values(1,2),(3,4)) select * from t) loop
        foo := r.y + 7;
    end loop;
exception
    when others then raise notice '%', r;
    raise;
end $$;
```

Output:

```
NOTICE:  (3,4)
ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 1, scale 0 must round to an absolute value less than 10^1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at assignment
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE  Tickets as t
SET     ticketPrice = ticketPrice-3
FROM    Showings as s
WHERE   s.priceCode = t.modTicket
```

**[Documentation of UPDATE Query](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/)**

Comment: I removed it and got this error: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "showings"